# Shifting un ordered list items to the left ( Wordpress )

Tags: css, wordpress

Hi I am having trouble shifting a menu list on my wordpress site to the left. It appears as if there is a margin so when the list contains so many items it appears right offset and no longer centred. The site in question is www.cabinboys.ca the menu I'm talking about is right below the cabinboys image filled with two letter items. If any one could look at my css and see if they could figure out how to shift the list items to the left that would be much appreciated thanks.

```
/* =Menu
----------------------------------------------- */
#menu {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 800px;
}
#menu img {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#menu a {
    color: #666;
    font-family: 'Oswald', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#menu a:hover {
    color: #36bcab;
}
#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 30;
}
#menu li {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
#menu ul ul {
    display: none;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
}
#menu ul ul ul {
    right: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
#menu ul ul a {
    background: #e9e9e9;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: 0 ;
    padding: .8em .5em .8em 1em;
    width: 130px;
}
#menu ul ul li:last-of-type a {
    border-bottom: none;
}
#menu li:hover > a,
#menu ul ul :hover > a {
    color: #36bcab;
}
#menu ul ul a:hover {
    background: #36bcab;
}
#menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#menu ul li.current_page_item > a,
#menu ul li.current_page_ancestor > a,
#menu ul li.current-menu-item > a {
    color: #111;
}
#menu ul:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Given your current CSS, the menu is never going to be centered, since you are floating all of the menu items right. Is you goal to have the menu of two-letter names centered on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a couple of properties to make it work:

```
#menu-header-menu {
    display:table;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
}
```

Nevertheless it's interesting that you say that the shift happened when the number if items in the menu increased, I don't see in the CSS any code that could differentiate the display depending on the number of items. Could you confirm that I understood the situation?

Comment: Thanks so much Grzegorz I just meant that when there are four less items in the list, the list appears centred and pleasing to the eye. It's just when you add those last few that extend further right then the ones on the left side do towards the left it looks lopsided